# Scala code to check if parenthesis are balanced

Tags: algorithm, scala

I'm writing a scala function to check for balanced parentheses. So `"()","([]{})"` are both balanced, but `")","(){[}]"` aren't balanced

Below is the code I wrote which should be working. I have no idea why it say's false for all inputs I try.

```
package general

import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

object BalanceParen {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        print(isBalanced("()"));
    }
    def isBalanced(input: String): Boolean = {
        val stack = new Stack[Char]
        val brace = HashMap('(' -> ')', '[' -> ']', '{' -> '}')

        input map (( ch: Char ) => {
            if( brace contains ch ) stack push ch
            else {
                if( brace.isEmpty )              return false
                if( brace.get(stack.pop) != ch ) return false
            }
        })
        return stack.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Comment: in the previous comment I totally overlooked `brace.get(stack.pop)` **but** `brace.isEmpty` looks like it should be `stack.isEmpty` ... but that should not be the bug behind your function returning `false` all the time

Comment: your code **works** for me by the way!

Comment: That's strange, have you tried other inputs, e.g `")))","(){}(]","({}(])"` ?

Comment: yes, for those it returns `false`, as expected :D

Comment: oh yes, and you need what @Shadowlands said... should have told you

Comment: thanks, got it working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap`'s `get` method returns an `Option`, so your test needs to change to something like:

```
if( brace.get(stack.pop) != Some(ch) ) return false
```

or:

```
if( brace.get(stack.pop).contains(ch) ) return false
```

Comment: I'm so stupid, I fixed that the second I copied his code to my IDE and forgot about it... you deserve that one :D

Comment: Indeed! that solved my problem :) I don't know much about how scala Options work, will read up on that. Thanks, and thanks to you too, olydis

Answer (score 2):

Why use stack if you can recurse with immutable structures.

```
def isBalanced(values: String): Boolean = {
  // If you would like to add or remove braces that need validation,
  // just change balanceMap
  val balanceMap = Map(
    ')' -> '(',
    '}' -> '{',
    ']' -> '['
  )
  val closedBraces = balanceMap.keys.toSeq
  val openBraces = balanceMap.values.toSeq

  @tailrec
  def isBalancedRec(parsed: Seq[Char], input: Seq[Char]): Boolean = {
    if (input.isEmpty) {
      if (parsed.isEmpty) {
        true
      } else {
        false
      }
    } else {
      input.head match {
        case in if openBraces.contains(in) =>
          isBalancedRec(in +: parsed, input.tail)
        case in if closedBraces.contains(in) =>
          if (parsed.isEmpty) {
            false
          } else if (parsed.head == balanceMap(in)) {
            isBalancedRec(parsed.tail, input.tail)
          } else {
            false
          }
        case _ => false
      }
    }
  }
  isBalancedRec(Nil, values.toCharArray)
}
```

Test cases:

```
isBalanced("())") // false
isBalanced("(){}[]") // true
isBalanced("{(})") // false
isBalanced("{([])}") // true
isBalanced("") // true
```

Comment: This will fail with test case : "(Scala Deverloper)"

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.java.run;

public class Traversetwoside {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "{<()>}";
        boolean istrue = true;

        int i, j = 0;
        for (i = 0, j = s.length() - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {

            // a=s.charAt(i);

            if (s.charAt(i) == '{') {
                if (s.charAt(j) != '}') {

                    istrue = false;
                    System.out.println("istrue =false");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (s.charAt(i) == '<') {
                if (s.charAt(j) != '>') {
                    istrue = false;
                    System.out.println("istrue =false");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
                if (s.charAt(j) != ')') {
                    istrue = false;
                    System.out.println("istrue =false");
                    break;
                }
            }
            istrue =true;
            System.out.println("istrue =true");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is meant to answer, but I don't think it does, and it's written in Java when the original question is about a Scala implementation of an algorithm, you'll probably get downvoted if you leave this here

Answer (score 0):

```
    **This will be using stack **



import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
object Valid_Parentheses {
def isValid(s: String): Boolean = {
var test = true
var stack = Stack[String]()
breakable {
  for (a <- 0 to s.length() - 1) {
    var char = s.charAt(a)
    if (char == '(' || char == '{' || char == '[') {
      stack.push(char.toString())
    }

    if (stack.isEmpty) {
      test = false
      break
    }

    if (char == ')' || char == '}' || char == ']') {
      var c: String = ""
      char match {
        case ')' =>
          c = stack.pop()
          if (c == "{" || c == "[") {
            test = false
          }
        case ']' =>
          c = stack.pop()

          if (c == "(" || c == "{") {
            test = false
          }
        case '}' =>
          c = stack.pop()
          if (c == "(" || c == "[") {
            test = false
          }
      }

    }

  }
}
if (!stack.isEmpty) {
  test = false
}

return test
}
def main(args: Array[String]) {
println(isValid("()"))
println(isValid("(}"))
println(isValid("[]}"))
println(isValid("(Scala developer)"))
}
}
```

*Output*

1. true
   2.false
   3.false
   4.true